# Ubuntu kernels in grub

Tags: grub2

Where would I find Ubuntu Kernel in the grub menu? Do I need to go into? I need to access it to mount Windows files using the file manager.

Comment: IIRC, you can boot a specific kernel from the Advanced Options for Ubuntu menu in GRUB.

Comment: I went to Advanced options. This is what it showed: Ubuntu, with Linux 5.0.0-37 - generic (recovery mode) was there also. It's GNU GRUB version 2.02. I still cannot access Ubuntu Kernel. Any suggestions?

Comment: To mount windows partition to access it, should only need to open up disks program, find your windows partition, click on it and should see three little squares under the big box showing partitions.  The one on the left(first one) will mount or unmount the partition.  You should not need to access the kernel, the kernel is running Ubuntu.

Comment: How do I know which one is Windows?I am new at this.

Comment: Are you trying to mount windows so that you can boot from it or are you just simply trying to browse the files of your windows partition ?

Comment: Windows and ubuntu should the two biggest sizes.  Ubuntu if clicked on will show a small black square in the left hand box.  Windows if not mounted, will show a triangle on it's side(play symbol).  Moving the mouse over the box will have a little popup saying mount.

Comment: I have 3 small boxes (one on left and 2 on right) of a large box in middle. The small box on the left when clicked says: NTFS/exFAT/HPFS(Bootable) NTFS-NOT MOUNTED. Then the large box in the middle when clicked says the same as that. The top small box( on the right of big middle box) when clicked says: extended partition. The bottom small box(on right of middle box) when clicked says: Linux-mounted at File System Root. Hope this makes some sense to you. Can you give me instructions with that info?

Comment: NTFS is the windows file system. Click on the large NTFS box to highlight it and just below those boxes should be three small icon boxes.  The first one should a triangle on it's side, moving the mouse over it should say 'mount selected partition'.  Clicking that box will mount windows, then you can follow instructions on your other question.  Do not unmount the linux partition.

Comment: I followed your instructions. Then I clicked on the link to where the files are stored. One problem though; I don't understand the codes that are under the files and I'm afraid to click on the files. Can you help me with this?

Comment: If you are back in files and have double click windows, it should open up a bunch of folders.  You only want the one with your windows user name and/or folders with names like downloads, documents,etc.  Just opening them will not cause problems.  Ubuntu should be able to read your personnel files.  When you find files you want, can copy them to the right folders in ubuntu.  Would not use the move option at this time.  Right clicking on files in windows will give you the options.

Comment: Why do I lose the shortcut (OS) on the DOCK? Is there any way I can keep this shortcut instead of having to go to disks every time I boot into Ubuntu? I will try what you suggested with the "documents file" in disks. I have no right click on this old laptop.

Comment: @crip659 Can you please tell me more step-by-step. I was able to access the files by name. I use short-cut keys for right-click. Options come up but not sure where to go to from there. Do I use Copy or Copy to? What are the steps after this please?

Comment: Copy to, it should give/ask for a location.  Use one of the folders in files or can make a new one.

Comment: Now I can get on with copying. Would you know if I can pin the OS icon to the Dock until I complete copying my files?( I don't know if I can do the copying all in one day) or do I have to go to disk and mount Windows again each time I want to copy? Hope this is clear for you. Hard to describe in writing.

Comment: Windows might mount by itself now, but if it doesn't you know now how to mount it and it only takes a couple of clicks.  I would open a few files that you have copied just to make sure everything is working well before coping everything.

Comment: Can I copy the main folders instead of opening them and copying the contents?

Comment: Do not not know if you can just copy a windows folder.  Should be able to open the folder and copy all contents in one go, instead of one at a time.  It will take longer, so make sure computer can stay on.  You will find that google has a lot of answers for ubunu questions.

Comment: I was able to drag and drop the files into the folders. So far so good.